# How to Redirect to subfolder depending on controller name, passing the rest of URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a directory map like this

```
root
---.htaccess
---site    
------application
------css
------...
---blog
...
```

I am running Codeigniter on this server and I have my website and other stuff inside application folder. I want to run a wordpress blog in the same server, but in a sibling folder.

All requests like `mysite.com/controller/action/parameter1/...` must call a controller.php inside `site/application` folder and trigger an action passing parameter1, parameter2 etc as expected.

Unless the "controller" is "blog". Requests like `mysite.com/blog` must redirect to `blog/` folder, passing all parameters, and there's where i am going to run WP

Any ideas on how to write my .htaccess? Currently I got the following (I still didint create the `site` and `blog` folders, all codeigniter files are inside root)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(ico|js|css|jpg|png|gif|html|ico?g)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just exclude `blog` from your codeigniter rule as

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog/?$|index\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(ico|js|css|jpg|png|gif|html|ico?g)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Alternatively, you can exclude all the existing files and directories with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

To map the domains to their respective folders (assuming the names would match)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

So, `blog.com/post` would go to `/blog/post` and `site.com/page` to `/site/page`.

Comment: hey there. what if, eventually I want to change `/blog/` by a domain like blog.com that also points to my root folder in this server? so i'll got to domains pointing to the same place, `blog.com` and `site.com` so `site.com` goes to `site` folder and `blog.com` to `blog` folder? and would you explain where and in what case should I use these 2 conditions you added in the end?